# Cannot find tags after using 'set' method of an element with cElementTree library

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Here's my sample code:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

g = ET.Element('stuff')
g.set('foo','bar')
h = ET.ElementTree(g)
```

With that setup, here's what happens:

```
>>> g.iterfind('stuff')
<generator object select at 0x10d38fa00>
>>> _.next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration

>>> h.iterfind('stuff')
<generator object select at 0x10d38fa00>
>>> _.next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

I'd really rather not use `getiterator()` and iterate over the entirety of the tree every time (though i guess iterfind might be doing that behind the scenes). Why does it fail to find the thing? It works before i do the `set`, but not after.

Comment: Are you sure it works before you do the `set`? It doesn't for me, and it shouldn't. Your `stuff` node doesn't have any descendants named `stuff`, so `iterfind` (or `find`, which is a little easier to use for interactive debugging) returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no thing to find here. You've created a `stuff` node with no children, then asked it for all of its descendant `stuff` nodes, of which there are none.

It doesn't work before the `set` any more than after it:

```
>>> import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
>>> g = ET.Element('stuff')
>>> print g.find('stuff')
None
>>> next(g.iterfind('stuff'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

And if you place that under another node, it works with or without a `set` on either one:

```
>>> f = ET.Element('parent')
>>> f.append(g)
>>> print f.find('stuff')
<Element 'stuff' at 0x10edc5b10>
>>> f.set('foo', 'bar')
>>> g.set('foo', 'bar')
>>> print f.find('stuff')
<Element 'stuff' at 0x10edc5b10>
```